# Are bond angles constant?

Tags: bond, stereochemistry

I'd imagine the answer to the question posed in the title is no - bond angles are not constant. Covalent bonds are not infinitely rigid; hence IR as a spectroscopic technique.

If so, how can we accurately determine bond angles? What margin of error might we expect from an experimentally measured bond angle?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, bond angles are not constant. For example, the [low-energy IR absorption of water](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_absorption_by_water#Vibrational_spectrum) (at $1595 \:\mathrm{cm^{-1}}$) is from the [H-O-H bend](http://www.chemtube3d.com/vibrationsH2O.htm)

There are a few techniques to measure bond angles. For polar compounds, [microwave rotational spectroscopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_spectroscopy) can often be used on small molecules in the gas phase.

I'd guess though, that most bond angles are measured from crystal structures using [X-ray diffraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_crystallography).

Keep in mind that spectroscopic techniques always have a timescale associated with them. So any experimental measurement is time-averaged. In the case of bond angles, while the angle will change, the average value is the equilibrium - at some points, the vibration will create a larger bond angle, and at some points in time, the bond angle will be smaller.

Comment: X-ray crystallography is useful but then again many bond angles differ in the solid and gaseous phases; HOF and HOOH's dihedral angle come to mind. How's bond angle measurement done in the gas phase?

Comment: Gas phase measurements, as I mention above, are done with microwave rotational spectroscopy.