# How is bond angle of a molecule measured?

Tags: bond, molecular-structure

Simply, how are (average?) bond angles for simple (or complex) molecules such as methane or ethene measured (determined)?

I'm guessing that X Ray crystallography can be used to determine bond angles for, well, materials that have a regular crystalline form. However, is there some other technique for determining bond angles in non crystalline  molecules?

I have researched on Chemistry SE and on the wider web and I can't find this question addressed - which I find strange as it seems to me an elementary question. Apologies if this question has already been addressed in Chem SE - I just wasn't able to find it using my search terms. I can find many resources about predicting bond angle and none on measuring them.

Comment: One method is rotational spectroscopy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_spectroscopy

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/18777/72973

Comment: Also related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/57784/has-anyone-even-taken-a-picture-of-a-molecule-to-confirm-the-geometry-predicted/57818#57818 (I search "X-ray bond angle" on this site).

Comment: Thanks to both  for such quick, relevant and helpful links. @buck if you can post as an answer I will accept. karsten, as you have shown, most of the trick in getting the right answer is asking the right question. In other SEs (ahem , maths, ahem, CS) you get your knees cut off for asking anything other than a perfect question.

Comment: Of course for methane, there is no need to *measure* anything ... ;-)

Comment: @Karl. But surely that's exactly the point. Without evidence that C-H bond angles (or maybe bond lengths) are all the same then we haven't any *evidence* that orbital hybridisation has occurred.

Comment: @CliveLong Also without single crystal structure analysis, there is overwhelming evidence that methane has four chemically identical H atoms in a tetraedrical arrangement, resp. that excludes any possible alternatives. Rotational and vibrational spectroscopy, NMR, heat capacity, powder diffractometry, isotope substitution experiments ...

Comment: @karl. Thanks for listing all the other methods/techniques.

Comment: Your question was sth else, however: What are the methods (apart from theoretical calculation) to determine absolute angles / distances in molecules that do not crystallise. Rotational spectroscopy applies to very simple gaseous molecules, which could also be crystallised. Right?

Comment: @CliveLong Orbital hybridisation doesn’t *occur*; it’s just a mathematical convenience we’ve adopted in order to describe the tetrahedral geometry. You don’t actually need sp3 orbitals to explain why methane is tetrahedral.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most obvious method is single crystal xray crystallography, of course, and for simple molecules, IR and microwave spectroscopy in the gas phase can be used.

For many complex (e.g. bioorganic) molecules, this fails, but there are two (afaik) last hopes to help solve/prove structures if they don´t crystallise and the usual NMR spectroscopy with added computational chemistry is not enough.

1. Single molecule xray diffraction, a very new approach that can only just be done on the one most brilliant xray "laser" source in the world, the XFEL in Hamburg. It cost 1.2 billion euros to build, and this is the "killer" application it is supposed to prove feasible.
2. RDC (*residual dipolar coupling*) measurements with NMR, a very fancy method where the interesting compound is trapped in an oriented (sort of "stretched") gel. If the molecules of the compound have a preferred orientation in that gel (they usually do, because very few biomolecules are spherical), you observe dipolar splittings in the spectra, which would normally be averaged out due to the free tumbling of the molecules. These couplings can be used to calculate relations between distances and angles between the magnetic field and the direct connecting line between the atoms involved.

No 2 of course relies heavily on additional input from conventional (spectroscopic) methods and computer simulations.

Comment: I tried finding data on 1H-13C NOEs for methane but had a hard time. That should be a pretty good way to obtain bond distances I would think. For simple molecules simulation (I am thinking of RDCs) should not always be necessary, depending on the amount of data. Motional averaging is always an issue, but presumably also for rotational spectroscopy.

Comment: @BuckThorn interesting thought - AFAIK, heteronuclear NOEs are not all that popular and have mostly focused on abundant nuclei like 1H/19F. Even then, going from a NOE intensity to an actual distance is not trivial; for homonuclear NOEs you need a “reference” peak for which you already know the distance (eg a geminal CH2 which can be accurately calculated computationally). In methane this would not be possible as there is only one 1H/13C NOE. Not sure if anybody’s actually tried doing it on a labelled protein, though. (see eg Craig Butts’ work for the small molecule stuff I mentioned earlier.)

Comment: @orthocresol Heteronuclear NOEs are often measured for specific applications in protein NMR and since 13C/15N labelling is commonly performed their measurement has become fairly routine. For something like methane you probably have to go back a half century to find studies in the literature on the determination of its bond length from NMR. The catch is that you have two unknowns, the bond length and the rotational correlation time, but I'm sure it's been done (or rather I'd be extremely surprised if it hasn't).

Comment: @BuckThorn good to know, thanks. :-) Yes the two unknowns issue is why reference peak is needed in that procedure. Going very offtopic here, but do you happen to know how one might otherwise determine $\tau_c$?

Comment: @orthocresol For protons in methane this does not appear to be simple because there are a number of different relaxation mechanisms. A seminal ref is J. Chem. Phys. 39, 552 (1963). It might be complicated even for 13C but I'm still trying to find the relevant ref.

Comment: @karl. A very thorough and actually understandable answer. Thanks to you and all other contributors.